# What is @synchronized key in obj-c equivalent of Swift GCD

Tags: swift, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

I need to do some synchronization with `@synchronized` in Obj-C and also need to sync some code in Swift using GCD.

In `@synchronized` we pass an object as key but what is its equivalent in GCD? It seems there isn't any way to pass key in GCD.

Comment: You can use a serial queue or actor in Swift.

Comment: There is no equivalent. Generally you shouldn't use `@synchronized` in ObjC, either. Just use GCD in both cases. For more on replacing mutexes (such as `@synchronized`) with GCD, see https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ThreadMigration/ThreadMigration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH105-SW1

Comment: (BTW, `@synchronized` was created in 10.3, several years before GCD was released in 10.6. It was handy at the time, but GCD was created to get rid of the need for that kind of tool. There still are reasons to use locks rather than GCD, particularly for low-level code, but generally the right answer in that case is some form of os_unfair_lock, and in the future OSAllocatedUnfairLock, rather than a tool like `@synchronized`.)

Comment: Strongly disagree with @RobNapier here. I always try to use the highest-level abstraction that gets the job done. `os_unfair_lock`, mutexes, GCD queues, etc. are all lower level abstractions than @synchronized. If all you need is to protect the value of a property in an Objective-C class, feel free to use it. If the situation is more complex, find the right tool for the job, but you haven't given us enough info to know what that would be.

Comment: `@synchronized` is exactly a mutex. The higher level abstraction here would be an OperationQueue rather than DispatchQueue. The link above gives a very good explanation on why Apple encourages a move towards queues (either Operation or Dispatch) over mutexes (including thin wrappers on mutexes like `@synchronized`.) When a mutex is the right tool for the job, it's because you're working at a low level. Note that all forms of queues were ported to Swift. `@synchronized` was not (which is a hint about whether it's favored...), so the answer in any case is "you can't."

Comment: The same is true, for the same reasons, for the ObjC `atomic` attribute.